# How to set a date for each value to increment from the previous value

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Hey there can anyone help me and give me examples. I am still developing in Access.
I got open hours which start with 2000 and closing hours that start with 4000 and I got a date value for instance 4/24/2013 if I enter a new date like tommorow 4/25/2013 then the closing hours of 4000 will become the opening hours 4000 can this be done using macros queries vba if you understand what I mean can you please provide me with this code and examples. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.  Can you edit your question and upload some code showing what you're trying to do?  Perhaps that'll make it easier to follow.

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by 2000 & 4000. Those don't look like times to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a form to create new entries and you have text boxes for the hours you could use `DMax` in the open hours text box to get the previous value from the closing hours.

`DMax("ClosingHours", "TableName")`

You can also use this within VBA Code.  If you could tell us more about these values, how you are adding them and what you want to achieve a better response could be provided.